# HTML Selectbox value ajax call using for page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've made a select box:

```
<select name="template" id="template" class="select">
<option value="template">Template_NL</option>
<option value="template_fr">Template_FR</option>
</select>
```

If the user changed the select box, I want to change a url based on that value on server side. Can I do that with an ajax request?

```
<script>$(function() { 
 $("#template").change(function() {
 var Template = document.getElementById("template").value;

 $.ajax({ 
 url: "mailing-edit2.asp", 
 data: Template, 
 success: function(){
 data = response;
 location.reload();
 }});
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add response to the callback call as parameter :

```
$("#template").change(function() {
     var Template = document.getElementById("template").value;

     $.ajax({ 
         url: "mailing-edit2.asp", 
         data: {'template': Template}, 
         success: function(response){
             //If you return the new url
             location.href = response;
         }
     });
 });
```

**NOTE :** The `location.href` will redirect you to the given url.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how get i the response value on the server side?

Comment: You recieve the `template` value on the server side, to return something from the server side to the `response` you should use `echo` (example : `echo 'my_url.com'`)

Comment: But further on the page i've got:
 Dim template
        template = Request.Form("template")
sRawContent = getContentText("template")

how change that value real time with the selectbox?

Comment: In server side, <%="www.example.com"%>

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question so we could see the bigger picture.

Comment: see my answer, i want to make the template dynamic

Comment: That isn't clear to me at all i'm sorry. try please to describe what you want to achieve clearly.

Comment: In the selectbox the user got the possibility to choose a template, on the same page is the template displayed. If the user select a other template it must be change directly on the page

Comment: In the Ajax call, try reload the page with the template parameter appended, and get the template name  from the URL when the page is loaded

Comment: I am not familiar with asp , but I guess the code inside ur padding-cell is sever side script which would not be able to detect ur front end changes like the form input.

Comment: Ok please check the content of `Request` after the change of the select.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr valign="top">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <td class="invoer-rijlabel" align="left">&nbsp;template&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="invoer-rijdubbelepunt" align="left" nowrap>:</td>
  <td class="invoer-rijinhoud" align="left"><select name="template" id="template" class="select">
                                            <option value="template">Template_NL</option>
                                            <option value="template_fr">Template_FR</option>
                                            </select></td>
 <script>
     $("#template").change(function() {
     var Template = document.getElementById("template").value;

     $.ajax({ 
         url: "mailing-edit2.asp", 
         data: {'template': Template}, 
         success: function(response){
              location.reload();
         }
     });
 });
 </script>
</tr>

  <td colspan="3" align="center" style="padding: 4px;">
    <div id="padding-cell">
        <%
        Dim asMonths, sDatumString
        Dim sRawContent, sBlock
        Dim template
        template = Request.Form("template")

        asMonths = array("0", "januari", "februari", "maart", "april", "mei", "juni", "juli", "augustus", "september", "oktober", "november", "december")

        sDatumString = day(dDatum) & " " & asMonths(month(dDatum)) & " " & year(dDatum)




        sRawContent = getContentText("template")
        sRawContent = replace(sRawContent , "%FULLURLROOT%", "https://www.manandshaving.nl/")             

        sBlock = split(sRawContent, "%SECTION%")(1)

        sBlock = replace(sBlock, "%DATE%", sDatumString)
        sBlock = replace(sBlock, "%SUBJECT%", sOnderwerp)        
        sBlock = replace(sBlock, "%CONTAINER_EDIT_MODE%", " style=""left: 0px; margin-left: 0px;""")
        sBlock = replace(sBlock, "%FOOTER_EDIT_MODE%", " style=""left: 0px; margin-left: 0px;""")

        if bSettingsMailingTemplateOverruleBodyStyle = true then
          sBlock = replace(sBlock, "%BODYSTYLE%", "")
        end if

        sBlock = replace(sBlock, "%UNSUBSCRIBE_LINK%", sSettingsMailingUnsubscribeLink)

        if trim(sHTML) = "" then
          sHTML = "<b>" & sSettingsDefaultMailingContent & "</b>"
        end if        

        sBlock = replace(sBlock, "%CONTENT%", "<textarea name=""txtContent"" id=""txtContent"" style=""height:500px; width: 100%; overflow: scroll;"">" & sHTML & "</textarea>")

        response.write(sBlock)
        %>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
```